# How to count data from Another Model in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have 2 models and i want to count `Foreignkey` data, I am trying to count the number of records in related models, but I am unable to count the records, Please let me know how i can Count the data. I want to count this data after filter, I am filtering between 2 dates, it's giving me the current data of using model in filter,but i want to count related model data also using filter.

Here is my `models.py` file...

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=225)
    customer=models.ForeignKey(Brand, related_name='product_customer',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user= models.ForeignKey(Supplement, related_name='product_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

here is my `views.py` file...

```
def index(request):
data = Project.objects.all()
  if request.method == 'POST':
     v1= request.GET.get('created-at')
     if v1:
         v2 = v1.split(' - ')
         s1 = v2[0]
         s2 = v2[1]
         result = Product.objects.filter(created_at__range=[s1,s2])
return render(request, 'index.html' {'result':result})
```

here is my `index.html` file..

```
<p>{{result.count}} product</p>
<p>{{result.product_customer.count}} Customer</p>
<p>{{result.product_user.count}} User</p>
```

I want to display this data after filter, for `product` it's working perfect, but i want to display data for `customer` and `user` when user filter...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the fastest way to do what you want is to use the `annotate` function that create new fields ...

```
result = Product.objects.filter(created_at__range=[s1,s2]).
        annotate(count_customers=Count('customer')).
        annotate(count_users=Count('user'))
```

... callable in the template:

```
<p>{{result.count}} product</p>
<p>{{result.count_customers}} Customer</p>
<p>{{result.count_users}} User</p>
```

Check the official [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet) for more infos